# Azure Cosmos DB (Graph API) - update a vertex immediately after inserting

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

SDK Used -

- Gremlin.Net
- .netcore3.1

Details of Cosmos account -

- **Type** - Graph API
- **Default Consistency** - Session
- **Replicate Data Globally** - 1 write region(West Europe) 2 Read regions(West Europe, UK South)

Event timeline -

- time T - g.AddV('').Property('id', 1).Property('pk', 1).Property('test', 'test')
- time T + 8ms - g.V([1,1]).Property('test1', 'test1')

**Issue observed** -
The update query did NOT update the vertex; and the response from gremlin client was 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the graph didn't create a  new vertex instead of updating the existing one?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31315095)